# Memory leak in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm currently developping a plugging for Wordpress. Recently I started having some issues when I tried opening a page of the website in my local installation. Whenever I try opening it in a new Chrome incognito window, I get a 500 error. Deleting cookies from the normal Chrome mode also triggers the problem.

Apache logs showed that I exhausted the maximum memory limit. Setting the limit to -1 results in infinite memory load so I have to manually halt apache execution. I then enabled xdebug and turned on debug mode. From what I understand xdebug comes with a maximum nesting limit, so that's the error I get now. Call stack shows that there is an loop of function calls.

Here is what it looks like:

```
( ! ) Error: Maximum function nesting level of '256' reached, aborting! in /.../wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 2030
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0008  397344  {main}( )   .../index.php:0
2   0.0010  397632  require( '.../wp-blog-header.php' ) .../index.php:17
3   0.0011  397984  require_once( '.../wp-load.php' )   .../wp-blog-header.php:13
4   0.0044  411632  require_once( '.../wp-config.php' ) .../wp-load.php:37
5   0.0046  413160  require_once( '.../wp-settings.php' )   .../wp-config.php:101
6   0.9406  10171032    do_action( )    .../wp-settings.php:375
7   0.9406  10171408    WP_Hook->do_action( )   .../plugin.php:465
8   0.9406  10171408    WP_Hook->apply_filters( )   .../class-wp-hook.php:310
9   0.9474  10227816    Classic_Editor::init_actions( ) .../class-wp-hook.php:286
10  0.9482  10229208    Classic_Editor::get_settings( ) .../classic-editor.php:42
11  0.9482  10229208    get_option( )   .../classic-editor.php:233
12  0.9484  10229528    W3TC\DbCache_Wpdb->get_row( )   .../option.php:100
13  0.9484  10229528    W3TC\DbCache_Wpdb->query( ) .../wp-db.php:2501
14  0.9484  10229528    W3TC\DbCache_WpdbInjection_QueryCaching->query( )   .../DbCache_Wpdb.php:167
15  0.9486  10229616    W3TC\Cache_File->get( ) .../DbCache_WpdbInjection_QueryCaching.php:143
16  0.9486  10229616    W3TC\Cache_File->get_with_old( )    .../Cache_Base.php:96
17  0.9486  10229616    W3TC\Cache_File->_get_with_old_raw( )   .../Cache_File.php:136
18  0.9486  10230048    W3TC\Cache_File->_get_path( )   .../Cache_File.php:154
19  0.9487  10230048    wp_hash( )  .../Cache_File.php:312
20  0.9487  10230048    wp_salt( )  .../pluggable.php:2259
21  0.9487  10230984    get_site_option( )  .../pluggable.php:2223
22  0.9487  10230984    get_network_option( )   .../option.php:1137
23  0.9488  10231024    get_option( )   .../option.php:1272
24  0.9490  10231344    W3TC\DbCache_Wpdb->get_row( )   .../option.php:100
.
.
.
252 0.9577  10249328    W3TC\DbCache_Wpdb->prepare( )   .../option.php:100
253 0.9577  10252168    array_walk ( )  .../wp-db.php:1378
254 0.9577  10252192    W3TC\DbCache_Wpdb->escape_by_ref( ) .../wp-db.php:1378
255 0.9577  10252192    W3TC\DbCache_Wpdb->_real_escape( )  .../wp-db.php:1258
256 0.9577  10252232    W3TC\DbCache_Wpdb->add_placeholder_escape( )
```

Lines 12 to 23 repeat till line 252.

I tried to set the max nesting level to 5000 but the limit is always attained.

Also, since the logs seem to imply that the problem comes from the W3 TC plugging, I tried disabling it. The problem dispeared for a bit and I was able to access the site in incognito mode but then resurfaced again after some time. Cleaning the cache using W3 TC also seems to temporarily resolve the problem.

From this point, I don't know what else I can try. How can I permanently solve this problem ?

Comment: "...but then resurfaced again after some time"   Can you please clarify? Did the problem resurface before or after you re-enabled the W3 TC plugin?

Comment: It might be helpful to see a debug trace when the problem occurs with W3 TC disabled.

Comment: @JamesHoux The problem was present with and without W3 TC being enabled. Also, the trace is always the same even with W3 TC disabled. Should I try and completely delete the plugin's folder ?

Comment: That sounds very suspicious.  As far as I knew, the way WordPress works, a plugin that is disabled should not be able to have any of its code run.  I've never heard of the behavior you are describing.  You could try deleting the W3 TC plugin folder to see what happens.

Comment: @JamesHoux So I deleted completely deleted W3 TC plugin following [this](https://www.thewebmaster.com/wordpress-articles/how-to-uninstall-w3-total-cache-manually/) tutorial. Everything is fine now. I still don't know how the plugin managed to work even after I disabled it.

Comment: Glad you solved it. Thanks for the follow up. That's helpful to know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems to be related to W3 TC plugin. Completely removing it fixed the problem for me.